# SQL Statement OR: show every row with the value in it malfunction

Tags: ms-access, select, sql

I have a very specific problem:

I have a List with Companies and different Roles to this companies in Access, everything in one Table, it look like this:

**Company // Role 1 // Role 2 // Role 3 // Role 4 //**

Comp1   // Ted    //        //        // Jimmy  //

Comp2   // Lin    //  Ted   // Andy   //        //

and so on...

I need now to make a sql statement which gives me every company (row) in which Ted, as an example, has a role.

I tried it like this in Access under SQL - Statement:

```
SELECT Firmen.Firma, Firmen.[Role1], Firmen.[Role2], Firmen.[Role3]
FROM Firmen
WHERE (((Firmen.[Role1])="Ted") AND ((Firmen.[Role2])="Ted") AND ((Firmen.[Role3])="Ted"));
```

But then it shows only rows where Ted is in the first column, I know there is a maybe stupid mistake in it and I had this problem already but I cant remember how I solved it last time.

Would be nice if you could help, because I really need it for work

Comment: you only have to Change your `AND`s to `OR`s and remove the parathesises. it doesn't matter which role ted has, and who has the other roles, correct?

Comment: Thats correct thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `and` logical operator instead of the `or` logical operator. Change it, and you should be OK. Or better yet, you could use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT Firmen.Firma, Firmen.[Role1], Firmen.[Role2], Firmen.[Role3]
FROM   Firmen
WHERE  "Ted" IN (Firmen.[Role1], Firmen.[Role2], Firmen.[Role3])
```

Comment: The in operator fits perfect. Thanks for the fast reply, that nearly safed my life, sorry for my stupidity